# How do you turn off G.SKill RGB lights on AsRock motherboard?

Tags: memory, motherboard, rgb

Before finalizing an order that would include

- RAM: G.Skill Trident Z RGB
- MB: AsRock Taichi X399

What will the options be for me to turn off RGB lights?
Searching, I read mainly topics about "Asus Aura". Is there an equivalent software for AsRock? Are there other ways?

Comment: ASRock mainboards come with [ASRock Polychrome](https://www.asrock.com/microsite/PolyChromeRGB/) and the Memory you mentioned is directly listed on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the Gskill RGB software? I haven't tried it because I have an ASUS motherboard, let me know if it works. https://gskill.com/en/download/view/trident-z-rgb-control